# Maven project does not referenced sikuli-api dependency in java

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, sikuli

I created Maven Project and I have an error, I think dependencies does not work.
`pom.xml` file does not read properly. `pom.xml` file has red x icon on it.

I edited the error is:

> Missing artifact com.sikulix:sikulixapi:jar:1.1.0

and this is my `pom.xml` file;

```xml
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.selin</groupId>
  <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>automation</name>
 <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>com.sikulix</id>
    <name>com.sikulix</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my class:

```
import org.sikuli.script.App;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class DefineObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App.open("G:\\mywork\\app.exe");

        Screen s = new Screen();

        s.wait("imgs\\a.png", 9000);
        s.find("imgs\\b.png");
        s.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sikuli was now renamed [SikuliX](http://www.sikulix.com/). You can depend on Sikuli Script by having [this single dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sikulix/sikulixapi/1.1.0):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

As a side-note, you don't need to specify `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in your POM since this is the default value. The same goes for `<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>`.

As such, this would be the corrected and simplified POM:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.selin</groupId>
  <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>automation</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
      <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But now pom.xml file has red x icon on it. :(

Comment: @SelinGungor I edited with the complete POM along with more info.

Comment: Still has error with this POM too with red x icon :( Missing artifact com.sikulix:sikulixapi:jar:1.1.0 @Tunaki

Comment: @SelinGungor Can you post a pastebin of your log? Also, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Tunaki I am still running into this issue. I also tried adding the <repository> to ~/.m2/settings.xml but still cannot compile. The workaround is manually adding the sikulixapi.jar to my classpath in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.aiur</groupId>
  <artifactId>GUIAutomationTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>GUIAutomationTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <!-- OSSRH: com.sikulix -->
        <id>com.sikulix</id>
        <name>com.sikulix</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <!-- <version>3.8.1</version> -->
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.1.0</version> -->
        <version>1.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```