# Classes not found in maven project despite the library being included in the pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, sikuli

I'm trying to run this open-source project, rokuality-server (full codebase here: https://github.com/rokuality/rokuality-server).

But in this method below I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to instantiate any Sikuli classes like `Pattern` or `Finder`.

```java
import org.sikuli.script.Finder;
import org.sikuli.script.Image;
import org.sikuli.script.Match;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ImageUtils {
    private static JSONObject getElement(String sessionID, String locator, File screenImage) {
        JSONObject element = new JSONObject();
        element.put(SessionConstants.ELEMENT_ID, UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        boolean isFile = locator != null && new File(locator).exists();
        boolean elementFound = false;

        if (!screenImage.exists()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (isFile) {
            Finder finder = null;
            float similarity = Float.valueOf(
                    SessionManager.getSessionInfo(sessionID).get(SessionConstants.IMAGE_MATCH_SIMILARITY).toString());
            Pattern pattern = null;

            try {
                //******** THIS LINE BELOW THROWS THE ERROR ********
                pattern = new Pattern(locator).similar(similarity);
                finder = new Finder(screenImage.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.getRootLogger().warn(e);
            }
        }
        // more code here
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that something in the `pom.xml` file is wrong, so here's the Sikuli X Api dependency as it appears there:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.github.vidstige</groupId>
            <artifactId>jadb</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulix2tigervnc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I tried changing the version to the latest one, `2.0.0` but it caused some errors in the project, which I think are related to changes in the `org.sikuli.script.Image` class's methods. Do I maybe need an earlier version?

Comment: I found this question on StackOverflow which is related, but has to do with how Sikuli was renamed to SikuliX: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672702/maven-project-does-not-referenced-sikuli-api-dependency-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed in the newer releases of the rokuality project:
https://github.com/rokuality/rokuality-server/releases. It depended on the java jdk version the user was running.